POST in Webhook Data fields get formatted as a one string issue when posted with a file object
I've encountered an issue when using Webhook (POST). When I include a file object in the POST request, the data field options get formatted as a single string, like this:
Array ( [data] => client_id=3&order_number=12345 )
However, when I don't include a file object, the data field options are sent separately, which is the desired format:
Array ( [client_id] => 3 [order_number] => 12345 )
Is there a way to send the data field options separately even when I POST a file object together?
FYI,
My API is developed using PHP and used print_r($_POST); to check how the data fields get passed to my API
I looked up zapier community post and other stack overflow writes, but none of them were helpful unfortunately
